# How to play a video in surface view

Tags: android

I want to play a video giving fixed height and width, not whole screen.
Can anybody tell me how to play the video in a surface view on android? Please provide sample code

Thanks

Comment: What have you already tried? And as a side point: try to always be polite.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a [VideoView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html) is what you want. I found some sample-code [here](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-videoview-example).

Answer (score 0):

Please try below:

```
surfaceholder.setFixedSize(width,height);
```